# CKEditor's autogrow event not firing

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.4.1 built using the builder on the website with the autogrow plugin in inline mode.

`CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline` is set to true.
`CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_onStartup` is also set to true.

I then proceed to inline a `contenteditable` like so:

```
var editor = Y.one('...'); //Get the contenteditable using YUI.

var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.inline(editor.getDOMNode());

ckEditor.on('instanceReady', function(e){
  console.log(e);
}, this);

ckEditor.on('autogrow', function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

I can confirm that the autogrow works properly and the inlined contenteditable expands when required. The `instanceReady` event also fires.

However, the `autogrow` event never fires when the contenteditable expands or shrinks.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AlfonsoML mentioned, the autogrow event does not work on inlined editors.

Therefore, I decided to do my own detection and fire my own events. One hack is to [apply a short transition and listen on transitionend](http://www.prevent-default.com/detect-size-change-of-elements-using-transitions/). However, older browsers do not support transitions and there are other issues associated with the `transitionend` event not firing under some circumstances.

The solution I used is to have a `setInterval()` running every `500ms`. Every `500ms`, we check the height of the `contenteditable` using `getComputedStyle()` and compare it against the stored previous height.

If there's a change, an event is fired.

This method is pretty robust and works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

The autogrow plugin is meant to be used in the framed mode. If you use inline mode then it will adjust automatically without the need of any plugin.

Comment: Is there any way to detect when the height of the container changes in inline mode?

Comment: Check any "normal" (I mean: this is not something specific to CKEditor) DOM event related to this, I can't tell you for sure.